# ¿ ASP .NET es gratis?

Tags: c#, asp.net

tengo una duda pues quiero saber si desarrollar en ASP.NET es gratis o se tiene que pagar algo, ya que quiero desarrollar una aplicación web para la empresa donde estoy trabajando.

Comment: Hay mucho más que tener en cuenta. Sí es gratis. Sí es open source, pero, dónde alojas tu aplicación? Si es IIS necesitarás WindowsServer. Tu empresa tiene esa licencia? Dónde vas a alojar tu base de datos? OnPremise? On Cloud? Es una aplicación de uso interno?

Comment: La aplicación web está alojado en IIS de Windows Server pero no tiene licencia, y la aplicación solo es para uso interno.

Comment: Para utilizar Visual Studio Community, como sugería una respuesta antes de ser borrada, recuerda que tu empresa no debe tener más de 250 computadoras o ganar 1 millón de dólares al año, según la [licencia de VSCommunity](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/mlt031819/). **Sugiero le preguntes a tu supervisor**

Comment: He hecho está pregunta por que en la empresa donde trabajo quieren migrar todo el sistema desarrollado en ASP .NET a PHP, por que PHP el libre. El sistema que está desarrollado en ASP .NET es para exportar muchos reportes con muchísima data. ¿ Tu que me recomendarías?¿El PHP sería bueno para un sistema de ese tipo?

Comment: Esa es otra pregunta, y es abierta a muchas interpretaciones. Qué te recomiendo? Que investigues. Necesitarán expertos en la materia. Depende de lo que estén migrando: Si tienen servicios **SOAP** en **WCF** y lo quieren pasar a un equivalente en PHP, buena suerte... Pero si tienen un par de sitios web en WebForms y quieren pasarlo a Wordpress, tal vez no cueste tanto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Home de asp]
Efectivamente, [asp.net](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/intellectualproperty/copyright/default) es gratis, y open source además.

En el enlace de arriba puedes ver los términos de uso.